# dynamically created textbox does not post value

Tags: php, jquery, yii2

This is my code for dynamically create textbox

```
$("#addfee tr").last().after("<tr><input name=\'Detail[" + $("#invoicedetail-item_id").val() +"][item_id]\' type=\'hidden\' value=\'" + $("#invoicedetail-item_id").val()+ "\' >"
+"<td><input type=\'text\' value=\' "+ $("#invoicedetail-item_id").find(":selected").text()+"\'readonly=\'readonly\'class=\'form-control\'></td>"
+"<td><input type=\'text\' name=\'Detail[" + $("#invoicedetail-tax").val() + "][tax]\' value=\'"+$("#invoicedetail-tax").val() +"\' readonly=\'readonly\'class=\'form-control\'></td>"
+"<td><input type=\'text\' name=\'Detail[" + $("#invoicedetail-unit_price").val() + "][unit_price]\' value=\'"+$("#invoicedetail-unit_price").val() +"\' readonly=\'readonly\' class=\'form-control\'></td>"
+"<td><input type=\'text\' name=\'Detail[" + $("#invoicedetail-quantity").val() + "][quantity]\' value=\'"+$("#invoicedetail-quantity").val() +"\' readonly=\'readonly\'class=\'form-control\'></td>"
+"<td><button>X</button></td></tr>");
}
```

in view dynamically new rows are added

But in controller

But it doesn't  go to the `if(isset($_POST['Detail'])`
condition 
Help me plz.......

Comment: how does the html look like after you append the texT?

Answer (score 1):

First of all use isset() and not isset[)
and are you posting with method POST or GET?

```
if(isset($_POST['Detail'])) {
  var_dump($_POST['Detail'];
}

if(!isset($_POST['Detail']) && isset($_GET['Detail'])) {
  echo 'Form method is wrong, GET is used by default not POST';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you should check `if(isset[$_POST['Detail']))`

Comment: sorry my condition is  if(isset[$_POST['Detail'])

Answer (score 0):

If you are submitting form using Jquery. then use following code for submitting dynamically added elements

```
$('#buttonSubmit').on('click', 'button', function(){
    // do something
});
```

https://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data-handler